# Magento CE: Home Page Tab stays on

Tags: magento, themes, admin

In Magento CE, Ultimo template, we are finding that the home page / house tab is staying active / colored (the background color surrounding the house stays colored), even when on another category page (where that tab is now highlighted).

How do you get it to shut off, so current category tab is all that is highlighted?

Comment: I suggest that you contact the developer behind the template ([link](http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798/support))

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to System > Configuration > Menu and disabled the Home link under menu bar tab.

Also, I suggest to read the documentation of ultimo first before tying to edit in the actual file as almost all theming are already in the admin.

Lastly, There is a discussion for ultimo theme user:
http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798/comments